Is the cluster key in AD Rights Management Service(RMS) the same as the private key for the SLC?
In AD RMS there is a Server Licensor Certificate that is responsible for encrypting content keys and such, and to do that a public-private key pair is generated.
I also know that RMS has something called a "cluster key" which you also set a password to during installation and configuration.
My question is, is the cluster key just the private key for the SLC? Or are they 2 different, separate keys for different purposes?
